# PHP Date() Function Minutes Behind

Tags: php

I have an odd situation, I am using the code below:

```
$currentTime = date("YmdHis");
echo 'Current Time = '.$currentTime;
echo '<br>';
```

When running this, sometimes it is running around 7 minutes too slow.. example:

[Image - Actual Time 11:35, PHP Current Time 11:27](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxOl9.png)

But then sometimes, it runs perfectly.. example:

[Image - Actual Time 11:37, PHP Current time 11:37](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwHi4.png)

Is there any reason why this is happening? I am basing calculations on the current time which is obviously causing problems when it is slow!

Comment: Is your server time exactly correct compared with whatever you're checking against?

Comment: Sounds like NTP drift on your server. You might want to ask this at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: Yes; presumably your server clock is drifting. You need to talk to whomever administrates the server, assuming that the time on your Mac is correct (normally Macs are pretty good timekeepers, as they're hooked up with decent NTP servers out-of-the-box.)

Comment: @MarkBaker I don't have direct access to the server, using hosting provided by 'FastHosts'

Comment: @user3498319 then you should contact FastHosts-support about this.

Comment: @rickdenhaan easier said than done! Do you know of any third party where I can reference the time in my code?

Comment: @user3498319 I'd advise you not to go down that route. The server should be doing that job for you; if it's faulty and your hosting service won't fix it, you should move hosts. It can cause all sorts of other problems; you won't have control over third-party code that you use which will assume the server time is correct.

Comment: @MattGibson I'll give them a call! Haven't been the most helpful in previous experiences